# Using PHPExcel to import contents of excel file into MySQL database (format problems)

Tags: php, mysql, date, format, phpexcel

I'm importing the contents of an Excel 2007 file into a MySQL database but the date field in the spreadsheet is a custom date format (dd-mmm-yy). I cannot change this to text because a client will be uploading it so it is not feasible. When I import the contents of the file it inserts the date as a number e.g. 40978 instead of 12-Jan-09. I know that changing the database table format of the field will have no effect as its excels formatitng but does anyone know a way around this? Without changing the format of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use PHPExcel's built in conversion methods like PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP() or PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject() to convert the date values to a PHP/Unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object respectively.

You can then format this to a yyyy-mm-dd format string using the appropriate PHP date() or $DateTimeObject->format() functions.

**EDIT**

```
$excelDateValue = 40978;

$PHPTimeStamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($excelDateValue);
echo $PHPTimeStamp,'<br />';
echo date('Y-m-d',$PHPTimeStamp),'<br />';
```

or

```
$excelDateValue = 40978;

$PHPDateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($excelDateValue);
echo $PHPDateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d'),'<br />';
```

Incidentally An Excel datestamp of 40978 is 10th March 2012 (based on the Excel Windows 1900 Calendar) or 11th March 2016 (based on the Excel Mac 1904 calendar). 12-Jan-09 would be an Excel timestamp of 39825 (based on the Excel Windows 1900 Calendar).

Comment: echo $PHPDateTimeObject->format('Y-m-d'),'<br />';
This is what I was missing :-) @Mark Baker

Answer (score 0):

Use code thar will convert the string date into a mysql formatted date. Something like:

```
$ma=array("jan"=>"-01-","feb"=>"-02-","mar"=>"-03-", etc );
$month=$ma[strtolower(substr($exceldate,3,3))];
$newdate="20".substr($exceldate,7,2).$month.substr($exceldate,0,2);
```

Comment: it converted all dates to 2040? @mlewis54

Comment: i think this is because 40978 is the number that is returned before it is imported into mysql so I need to work from this number